# Typescript react redux, property does not exist on type {}

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I am creating an authentication flow with react redux and typescript. I setup my signup auth state interface and initial state

```
export interface User {
  id: string;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  social: Social;
  userCourses: Course[];
  enrolledCourses: Course[];
}

interface AuthState {
  isAuth: boolean;
  usernamesAndEmails: UsernameAndEmail[] | [];
  currentUser: User | {};
  isLoading: boolean;
  error: object;
}

const signupInitialState: AuthState = {
  isAuth: false,
  usernamesAndEmails: [],
  currentUser: {},
  isLoading: false,
  error: {},
};
```

I then have a component where I need to use the currentUser state to have the user create their username (if they signed up with google/facebook).

```
const { currentUser } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth); 
const onSubmit = (data: FormData) => {
  dispatch(tryChangeUsername(currentUser, data));
};
```

But I am getting the error (Argument of type '{} | User' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User'.
Type '{}' is missing the following properties from type 'User': id, username, email, social, and 2 more.).
I'm not sure if I need to set up my interfaces or initial state differently or what. I think the issue is coming from the fact that current user can be an empty object (although it will not be in that component because that component will be a private route) but I'm not sure how to rectify the issue.

Comment: I recommand just passing `currentUser` to `tryChangeUsername()` and checking within that function if `currentUser` is type `User` or `{}`.

Comment: @ddcastrodd I tried that but still get basically the same issue. Right now I am getting currentUser like const { currentUser } = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.auth);  So I think the issue is that the currentUser object can be empty since its initial state is an empty object. But if i get currentUser through props then I don't have this issue. But I don't want to have to pass it down through props. I just want to be able to get it with useSelector.

Answer (score 0):

You should check whether currentUser is type User or {} before using its property

```
function isUser(object: User | {}): object is User {
    return 'id' in object;
}

let currentUser: User | {};

if (isUser(currentUser)) {
    // make something
    currentUser.id;
}
```